# Overriding a synchronized method

Tags: synchronization, overriding

What happens when a method in super class is synchronized, but you override the method in a subclass and don't synchronize it ?

Answer (score 5):

If a method in super class is synchronized, but you override the method in a subclass and don't synchronize it, then **the method is no longer synchronized if called on the subclass**.

Comment: Likewise, a subclass can add synchronization to a method that a superclass does not have synchronized.

Comment: If your subclass foo() method calls super.foo() then you will be synchronized during the super invocation.