# Is synchronized inherited in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, synchronized

I have superclass `Point` and a `synchronized` method `draw()`. Will the subclasses of `Point` inherit `synchronized` if I override method `draw()` in them or I have to always write it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding a synchronized method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173345/overriding-a-synchronized-method)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, you will always have to write `synchronized`. If you call the synchronized method of the super class this will of course be a synchronized call. `synchronized` is not part of the method signature.

See http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/mechanics.html for detailed description from Doug Lea, Java threading boss (or so).

Comment: Maybe clarify one detail: whether or not a given method call is synchronized depends on the dynamic type of the object it's called on, not the static type. That is, if `foo()` is `synchronized` in `Derived` but not in `Base`, and you assign a `Derived` to a `Base` variable and call `foo()` on it, that call will be synchronized. This point is implicit in 8.4.3.6 of the language spec (which says a `synchronized` method is equivalent to a `synchronized` statement within that method), but I couldn't find it spelled out anywhere else. Runnable demo [here](http://runnable.com/U4zBThIj5WNju2g2/).

Comment: Will calling `super.draw()` be still synchronized?

Comment: If `super.draw()` is synchronised, then of course it will.

Answer (score 8):

You can check it yourself by writing this:

```
public class Shape {

    protected int sum = 0;

    public synchronized void add(int x) {
        sum += x;
    }
}


public class Point extends Shape{

    public void add(int x) {
        sum += x;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

And test class

```
public class TestShapes {

    public final static int ITERATIONS = 100000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final Point p = new Point();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(int i=0; i< ITERATIONS; i++){
                    p.add(1);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(int i=0; i< ITERATIONS; i++){
                    p.add(1);
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();


        System.out.println(p.getSum()); // should equal 200000

    }
}
```

On my machine it was 137099 instead of 200000.

Comment: easier way to test would be to test on [`Thread.holdsLock(this);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock%28java.lang.Object%29) in the overridden method

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Test code could just expose a bug or a time anomaly due to something other than synchronization. The answer is to be found in the language specification.

Comment: @EJP At first I thought you were wrong. Then I realized you were actually right, but rather pessimistic...

Comment: I seriously discourage anyone from exploring like this. Your test might be correct in most cases but miss a very specific but very important aspect - and you'd never know until it bites you. Instead, **READ THE SPECIFICATION!** - then you *know*.

Answer (score 5):

your Overriden method will **no longer be synchronized** if you Override it and remove the `synchronized`. Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15493221/1515052) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=239066)

Comment: Neither of your citations is a normative reference.