# Is it ok to synchronize a overridden method in a subclass which is not synchronized in parent class?

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a derived class, and for some reason, I have to make two methods of this class synchronized to prevent them executing at the same time. One of the methods is an overridden method. Parent method is not synchronized.

Is it ok to synchronize the overridden method?

Comment: What are your concerns about doing so?

Comment: I just got the feeling that it may create some unexpected scenarios. But couldn't actually think of any unexpected scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998431/5226711

> synchronized is not part of the method signature.

So it is okay to synchronize the overridden method.

Comment: There is a difference between being able to do something and doing something which is best practice.

Comment: Your answer, which is correct, is saying that it is _possible_ to override a method and add `synchronized`.   But this does not necessarily mean that we _should_ be doing this.

Comment: Depends on the situation, doesn't it? Since the question does not describe the concrete circumstances, it can well be the case that OP has motivation for synchronization in a subclass.