# Java method synchronization inheritance

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, synchronization

I was reading through *The Java Programming Language, Fourth Edition*, and came across some confusing statements on synchronization in the "Threads" chapter. The information is as follows:

> The way that synchronization is enforced in a class is an implementation detail. The fact that it is enforced is an important part of the contract of the class and must be clearly documented--the precense of the `synchronized` modifier on a method might only be an implementation detail of the class, not part of a binding contract.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it makes sense to me that there could be an un-synchronized method that is then overloaded in a subclass's implementation of that method such that it *is* synchronized.

However...

If a class's method is declared synchronized, can that method be overridden (or is it overloading in this case?) in a subclass such that it is the exact same but without a `synchronized` clause? If not, are there *any* ways to override/overload a method in a subclass such that it is not synchronized when the superclasses implementation is?

Comment: Does [JLS-17.1. Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) help clarify what the book is saying? The distinction being on whether it is a *synchronized statement* ([**§14.19**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19)) or a *synchronized method* ([**§8.4.3.6**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173345/overriding-a-synchronized-method

Comment: If a sub-class overrides a method that is synchornized in the super-class but does not add the synchronized modifier itself, the sub-class method is not synchronized.  If the sub-class method calls super.method() then the super-class method is still synchronized.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't see anything explicit in the JLS sections you cite that says whether `synchronized` is or is not a heritable method attribute.  It's _implied_ though by the examples in 8.4.3.6 which proclaim that a synchronized method "has exactly the same effect as" a method whose entire body is a single synchronized block.  Method _bodies_ obviously are not inherited.